# How to add custom edge label in boost graph?

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I am using boost graph of type:

```
namespace boost {
      struct computable_object_t
  {
    typedef vertex_property_tag kind;
  };
}

typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, unsigned int,
                        boost::property<boost::computable_object_t,
                                        plComputableObject*> > slVertexProperty;

typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, slScoreValueType> slEdgeProperty;

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS,
                              slVertexProperty, slEdgeProperty> slGraph;
```

Now i have to add sting type edge label for each edge of the graph, further i could use them in my program to distinguish different kind of edges.

Please share you idea, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add that new label property to the list of edge properties (namespaces removed):

```
typedef property<edge_weight_t, slScoreValueType,
          property<edge_name_t, string> >
        slEdgeProperty;
```